# npm start is throwing error with exit code 126

Tags: mac, node.js, npm

So im working through a course on Pluralsight which has with a folder containing files required for the course. Part of the course requires me to install and run npm. It installed with a few issue, which required me to run npm audit fix. The dependency issues cleared but Im still having issues running npm start. Below is the console's response after running npm start and after that, separated by hash tags is a copy of the log output. Has anyone come across this and/or could anyone help with this?

```
###################################################
s/demos$ npm start

> html5-fundamentals@1.0.0 start /Users/briensmarandache/Atom_Projects/Pluralsight/HTML5/html5-fundamentals/demos
> http-server -o

sh: /Users/briensmarandache/Atom_Projects/Pluralsight/HTML5/html5-fundamentals/demos/node_modules/.bin/http-server: Permission denied
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 126
npm ERR! html5-fundamentals@1.0.0 start: `http-server -o`
npm ERR! Exit status 126
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the html5-fundamentals@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/briensmarandache/.npm/_logs/2019-04-23T22_39_37_214Z-debug.log

###################################################
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/local/bin/node', '/usr/local/bin/npm', 'start' ]
2 info using npm@6.4.1
3 info using node@v10.15.3
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle html5-fundamentals@1.0.0~prestart: html5-fundamentals@1.0.0
6 info lifecycle html5-fundamentals@1.0.0~start: html5-fundamentals@1.0.0
7 verbose lifecycle html5-fundamentals@1.0.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle html5-fundamentals@1.0.0~start: PATH: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/Users/briensmarandache/Atom_Projects/Pluralsight/HTML5/html5-fundamentals/demos/node_modules/.bin:/Users/briensmarandache/.rbenv/shims:/Users/briensmarandache/.rbenv/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands
9 verbose lifecycle html5-fundamentals@1.0.0~start: CWD: /Users/briensmarandache/Atom_Projects/Pluralsight/HTML5/html5-fundamentals/demos
10 silly lifecycle html5-fundamentals@1.0.0~start: Args: [ '-c', 'http-server -o' ]
11 silly lifecycle html5-fundamentals@1.0.0~start: Returned: code: 126  signal: null
12 info lifecycle html5-fundamentals@1.0.0~start: Failed to exec start script
13 verbose stack Error: html5-fundamentals@1.0.0 start: `http-server -o`
13 verbose stack Exit status 126
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:301:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:189:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:189:13)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:970:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:259:5)
14 verbose pkgid html5-fundamentals@1.0.0
15 verbose cwd /Users/briensmarandache/Atom_Projects/Pluralsight/HTML5/html5-fundamentals/demos
16 verbose Darwin 18.5.0
17 verbose argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "start"
18 verbose node v10.15.3
19 verbose npm  v6.4.1
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 126
22 error html5-fundamentals@1.0.0 start: `http-server -o`
22 error Exit status 126
23 error Failed at the html5-fundamentals@1.0.0 start script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 126, true ]
```

Answer (score 1):

With some help from this comment https://stackoverflow.com/a/59818130/3896144

It says that the script should have executable right, this worked in my case